# Trying to conditionally colour table cells background and font colour based on content, negative, positive and no change

Tags: html, jquery, css

Truly lost here.
Have looked at all related code snippets and can't make any work for me.

I need to conditionally format a table cells background color based on content.
Red for <0
Green for >0
White for 0

Also I need to be able to conditionally change the font color of **other** cells based on content.
Red for <0
Green for >0
Black for 0

I **now** have this for the background coloring so far, but it does not work as it should. (WORKS NOW)

**Have made it work for background finally!!**

**Just need the font color to work in the last three columns of my table.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>colored rating scale</title>
    <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"
    
  ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
table {
  width: 60em;
}

#name {
  width: 20%;
}

#symbol {
  width: 5%;
}

#thisrank {
  width: 10%;
}

#lastrank {
  width: 10%;
}

#change {
  width: 10%;
}
#marketcap {
  width: 15%;
}

#price {
  width: 15%;
}

#weekpc {
  width: 5%;
  
}
#monthpc {
  width: 5%;
}

#yearpc {
  width: 5%;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: center;
}

.up {
  background-color: #9f0;
  /*color:#9f0;*/
}

.nochange {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.down {
  background-color: #f30;
}
   
  </style>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
<p><br>
<b>This table is broke,  (NOW WORKS FOR BACKGROUND COLOR) BUT...<br> 

1. <u>font color</u> of "weekpc" , "monthpc" and "yearpc" should be red/green/no-color 
according to whether the contents are negative/positive/no-change in percentages.<br>
2. All fonts should be Arial.</b>

<table align="center">
  <col id="name" />
  <col id="symbol" />
  <col id="thisrank" />
  <col id="lastrank" />
  <col id="change" />
  <col id="marketcap" />
  <col id="price" />
  <col id="weekpc" />
  <col id="monthpc" />
  <col id="yearpc" />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th colspan="3">Rank</th>
      <th>Market Cap.</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Week %</th>
      <th>Month %</th>
      <th>Year %</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   
    <tr>
     <td align="left">      </td>
     <td align="left">      </td>
     <td align="center"><b> This Week   </b></td>
     <td align="center"><b> Last Week   </b></td>
     <td align="center"><b> Change  </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">  ABC Corp.   </td>
     <td align="left">  ABC </td>
     <td align="center">    1   </td>
     <td align="center">    1   </td>
     <td align="center"><b> 0   </b></td>
     <td align="right"> $686,270,744    </td>
     <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
     <td align="right"> 0%  </td>
     <td align="right"> 0.01%   </td>
     <td align="right">   0.02%  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">  DEF Corp.   </td>
     <td align="left">  DEF </td>
     <td align="center">    2   </td>
     <td align="center">    3   </td>
     <td align="center"><b> -1  </b></td>
     <td align="right"> $686,270,744    </td>
     <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
     <td align="right"> -10%    </td>
     <td align="right"> -15%    </td>
     <td align="right"> -25%    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">  GHI Corp.   </td>
     <td align="left">  GHI </td>
     <td align="center">    3   </td>
     <td align="center">    2   </td>
     <td align="center"><b> 1   </b></td>
     <td align="right"> $686,270,744    </td>
     <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
     <td align="right"> 10% </td>
     <td align="right"> 15% </td>
     <td align="right"> 25% </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>  



  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
  //get td text
    var change = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text().trim());
    console.log(change)
    //depending on condtion add class..
    if (change < 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('down')
    } else if (change > 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('up')
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('nochange')
    }

  });
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please tell if the number of cell's would be static or will it be dynamic, if it is static you could try adding class or id to each cell and check in javascript as (target cell).textContent < 0 or > 0 or = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get value of second `td` tag using `:eq(1)` and then depending on the value add class.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
    //get td text
    var score = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text().trim());
    //depending on condtion add class..
    if (score < 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('down')
      $(this).find("td:gt(6)").css({
        "color": "red",
        "font-family": "Arial"
      })
    } else if (score > 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('up')
      $(this).find("td:gt(6)").css({
        "color": "#9f0",
        "font-family": "Arial"
      })
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('nochange')
    }

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 20em;
}

#score {
  width: 50%;
}

#name {
  width: 50%;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: center;
}

.up {
  background-color: #9f0;
  /*color:#9f0;*/
}

.nochange {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.down {
  background-color: #f30;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center">
  <col id="name" />
  <col id="symbol" />
  <col id="thisrank" />
  <col id="lastrank" />
  <col id="change" />
  <col id="marketcap" />
  <col id="price" />
  <col id="weekpc" />
  <col id="monthpc" />
  <col id="yearpc" />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th colspan="3">Rank</th>
      <th>Market Cap.</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Week %</th>
      <th>Month %</th>
      <th>Year %</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> </td>
      <td align="left"> </td>
      <td align="center"><b> This Week   </b></td>
      <td valign="center"><b>    Last Week   </b></td>
      <td valign="center"><b>    Change  </b></td>
      <td><b>        </b></td>
      <td><b>        </b></td>
      <td><b>        </b></td>
      <td><b>        </b></td>
      <td><b>        </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> ABC Corp. </td>
      <td align="left"> ABC </td>
      <td align="center"> 1 </td>
      <td align="center"> 1 </td>
      <td align="center"><b> 0   </b></td>
      <td align="right"> $686,270,744 </td>
      <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
      <td align="right"> 0% </td>
      <td align="right"> 0.01% </td>
      <td> 0.02% </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> DEF Corp. </td>
      <td align="left"> DEF </td>
      <td align="center"> 2 </td>
      <td align="center"> 3 </td>
      <td align="center"><b> -1  </b></td>
      <td align="right"> $686,270,744 </td>
      <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
      <td align="right"> -10% </td>
      <td align="right"> -15% </td>
      <td align="right"> -25% </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> GHI Corp. </td>
      <td align="left"> GHI </td>
      <td align="center"> 3 </td>
      <td align="center"> 2 </td>
      <td align="center"><b> 1   </b></td>
      <td align="right"> $686,270,744 </td>
      <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
      <td align="right"> 10% </td>
      <td align="right"> 15% </td>
      <td align="right"> 25% </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Used your example, see how it works, thanx. Have edited my original question with more detail and example of what I am attempting to achieve as I am still stuck.

Comment: Backgound conditional coloring now works great! was initially confused by the eq(1) which I have edited to be eq(4) (COLUMN 5). Just need to conditionally change font color of last 3 columns now.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to update your if statement to include the other options, similar to the answer Swati provided:

```
  var result = function() {
    if (score <= -1) {
      return 'down';
    } else if (score >= 1) {
      return 'up';
    }
    return 'nochange';
  }
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr > td:odd').each(function(index) {
    var scale = [
      ['down', -1],
      ['nochange', 0],
      ['up', 1]
    ];
    var score = $(this).text();
    var result = function() {
      if (score <= -1) {
        return 'down';
      } else if (score >= 1) {
        return 'up';
      }
      return 'nochange';
    }

    $(this).addClass(result);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 20em;
}

#score {
  width: 50%;
}

#name {
  width: 50%;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: center;
}

.up {
  background-color: #9f0;
  color: darkgreen;
}

.nochange {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
}

.down {
  background-color: #f30;
  color: darkred;
}


/* EOS */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>colored rating scale</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <col id="name" />
    <col id="score" />
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mr Down</td>
        <td>-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No Change</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mr Up</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Another option would be to use a ternary operator to compare the scores, if you don't mind hard-coding the index values (you won't have more than those three options on the scale, for example):

```
    var result = (score <= scale[0][1]) ? scale[0][0] : (score >= scale[2][1]) ? scale[2][0] : scale[1][0];
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr > td:odd').each(function(index) {
    var scale = [
      ['down', -1],
      ['nochange', 0],
      ['up', 1]
    ];
    var score = $(this).text();
    var result = (score <= scale[0][1]) ? scale[0][0] : (score >= scale[2][1]) ? scale[2][0] : scale[1][0];
    $(this).addClass(result);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 20em;
}

#score {
    width: 50%;
}

#name {
    width: 50%;
}

th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: center;
}

.up {
    background-color: #9f0;
    color: darkgreen;
}

.nochange {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}

.down {
    background-color: #f30;
        color: darkred;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>colored rating scale</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <col id="name" />
    <col id="score" />
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mr Down</td>
        <td>-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No Change</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mr Up</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

To conditionally change the font color, you could just update the CSS classes `.up`, `.down`, and `.nochange` to include them as I've done in the snippets (unless you mean to change the font color of other cells besides the scores).

Comment: Have edited question to give real example now and managed to make the background work finally. Still need the font color functionality for OTHER cells/columns.